# HIVE - hive subquery is not working with case when statement with IN clause

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to migrate data from mysql to hive.I am not able to write a subquery case when statement with IN clause.This is my query. Can you Please help in this regard. AM i not following the proper syntax .

```
CREATE TABLE HIVE_TPCE_TEMP.TMP_CDMA_CD AS 
SELECT A.DRI,C.BOUND_ID,A.CT_ID,A.CD_ID,A.CID,
 A.TID,A.TASK_SEQ_ID,A.DIV_ID,C.BLOCK_GROUP_ID,C.ZIP_CODE,C.ROAD_CATEGORY_ID,A.RXPOWER,"${hiveconf:C_CDMA_DEVICE_ONLINE_RXPOWER_METRIC_ID}" METRIC_ID,
CASE WHEN 
     ((A.DRI,A.DIV_ID,A.RFID) in (SELECT DRI,DIV_ID,HOME_RFID FROM       HIVE_TPCE_TEMP.TMP_HOME_NETWORKS)) THEN 
    CASE WHEN MODE IN ('A','N') THEN "${hiveconf:HAD}" ELSE "${hiveconf:HD}" END
    WHEN (COALESCE(A.RFID,0) = 0) AND ((A.DRI,A.DIV_ID,D.FR,D.SUBBAND) IN (SELECT DRI,DIV_ID,HOME_FR,
          HOME_SUBBAND FROM   HIVE_TPCE_TEMP.TMP_HOME_NETWORKS))
    THEN CASE WHEN MODE IN ('A','N') THEN "${hiveconf:HAD}" ELSE "${hiveconf:HD}"  END
         ELSE CASE WHEN MODE IN ('A','N') THEN "${hiveconf:PAI}" ELSE "${hiveconf:PDI}" END END HPDA_ID
FROM HIVE_TPCE.VW_CDMA_CD A INNER JOIN HIVE_TPCE.STG_CURRENT_FILES B
     ON A.DRI = B.DRI AND A.SOURCE_FILE_ID   = B.SOURCE_FILE_ID
                 INNER JOIN
           HIVE_TPCE.WRK_LOCATION C 
     ON A.DRI = C.DRI AND A.LOCATION_ID = C.LOCATION_ID
                   INNER JOIN 
             HIVE_TPCE.LU_RADIO D
ON A.RADIO_ID = D.RADIO_ID  WHERE A.CID > 0  AND D.MODE IN ('A','N') AND A.RXPOWER IS NOT NULL   AND A.CALL_RESULT_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 16;
```

My error signature is

```
FAILED: ParseException line 10:42 mismatched input ',' expecting ) near 'DRI' in expression specification
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-subqueries.html): "Hive supports subqueries only in the `FROM` clause".

Your `CASE WHEN` is part of the `SELECT` clause, but it includes includes a `SELECT` subquery. Seems like that is not supported, so your syntax is not correct (in Hive).

Perhaps you could stage the data in MySQL using the query you have and then load it into Hive using a simple `SELECT` without `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: As Per HIVE manual, subqueries are supported in both WHERE and FROM clause https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries , but definitely not in SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

See [official document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT).
It says

> ### Assumptions
>
> We plan to limit the scope with the following assumptions and limitations.
>
> Subqueries could only be top-level expressions in SELECT. That is, subqueries in complex expressions, aggregates, UDFs, etc. will not be supported for now