# Hive syntax -- Comparision in Case when

Tags: hive

I am using Hive to do a comparison in CASE WHEN THEN statement . Can u please check whether my syntax is correct.

---

```
${hiveconf:Test Metric} METRIC_ID,               
    CASE 
      WHEN ((A.X,A.Y,A.Z)IN (SELECT X,Y,Z FROM HIVE_TPCE_TEMP.TESTTABLE))
        THEN CASE 
               WHEN MODE IN ('A','N') 
                 THEN ${
                         hiveconf:SOME_CONSTANT ELSE ${hiveconf: SOME_CONSTANT
                       } 
                  END
```

---

Comment: What happened, when you tried?

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 16:47 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'X' 'FROM' in expression specification .... This is the error signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your snippet of code is from the `SELECT` clause of your query? According to the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-subqueries.html): "Hive supports subqueries only in the `FROM` clause".

Your `CASE WHEN` statement includes a subquery. Seems like that is not supported, so your syntax is not correct (in Hive).

Comment: Can We implement same logic in hive with some other way or statement.

Comment: Difficult to tell without the whole query, but probably `LEFT JOIN` your `TESTTABLE` to the rest of the query rather than relying on the `IN` clause to find the entry you are looking for. You can then apply your `CASE WHEN` statement to the joined columns rather than using a subquery.

Comment: Too be entirely honest, this looks like one beast of a query. SQL (and especially HQL) was not really built for this kind of recursive lookups. Perhaps pure MapReduce would suit your requirements better?

Comment: Even I am thinking of a map reduce program . But dont u think it will be a overhead on performance if we compare to sql query execution.

Comment: Hive HQL queries are always translated into MapReduce in the backend. I do not think you need to be worried about performance overhead when you decide to write your own MapReduce programs, rather than relying on Hive to write them for you.

Comment: HI if possible . Please check the whole query . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588622/hive-hive-subquery-is-not-working-with-case-when-statement-with-in-clause)

Comment: As I suggested in that thread, I think you should consider staging the data in MySQL using the query you have and then loading it into Hive using a simple SELECT without CASE WHEN. That way you wouldn't need to go through the trouble of rewriting your query to HQL in the first place.